# How to configure the default index analyzer to a built in one

Tags: elasticsearch

On a field mapping I can set the analyzer like so:

```
{ ... ,"analyzer": "german", ... }
```

I would lie to set an analyzer for a whole index, at index creation time. According to the documentation, I need to configure the 'default' index:

```
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "default": {
        What do I need to put here?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what I need to put into the "analyzer" object, if I just want to use the build-in German analyzer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be the answer. I'm not sure how I can test that it works, but creating the index with these settings does not throw an error:

```
      "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "default": {
                        "type": "german"
                    }
                }
            }
```